# Segmentation fault while accessing a function-static structure via returned pointer

Tags: c, debugging, data-structures, segmentation-fault, shared-libraries

I have the following structure:

```
struct sys_config_s
{
  char server_addr[256];
  char listen_port[100];
  char server_port[100];
  char logfile[PATH_MAX];
  char pidfile[PATH_MAX];
  char libfile[PATH_MAX];
  int  debug_flag;
  unsigned long connect_delay;
};
typedef struct sys_config_s sys_config_t;
```

I also have a function defined in a static library (let's call it A.lib):

```
sys_config_t* sys_get_config(void)
{
  static sys_config_t config;
  return &config;
}
```

I then have a program (let's call it B) and a dynamic library (let's call it C). Both B and C link with A.lib. At runtime B opens C via `dlopen()` and then gets an address to C's function `func()` via a call to `dlsym()`.

```
void func(void)
{
  sys_get_config()->connect_delay = 1000;
}
```

The above code is the body of C's `func()` function and it produces a segmentation fault when reached. The segfault only occurs while running outside of `gdb`.

Why does that happen?

EDIT: Making `sys_config_t config` a global variable doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is trivial. Somehow, by a header mismatch, the PATH_MAX constant was defined differently in B's and C's compilation units. I need to be more careful in the future. (**facepalms**)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the variable being a static-local, or a static-global variable.  A static variable is STATIC, that means, it is not, on function-call demand, allocated on the stack within the current function frame, but rather it is allocated in one of the preexisting segments of the memory defined in the executable's binary headers.

That's what I'm 100% sure. The question, where in what segment they exactly placed, and whether they are properly shared - is an another problem. I've seen similar problems with sharing global/static variables between modules, but usually, the core of the problem was very specific to the exact setup..

Please take into consideration, that the code sample is small, and I worked on that platforms long time ago. What I've written above might got mis-worded or even be plainly wrong at some points!

I think, that the important thing is that you are getting that segfault in C when touching that line. Setting an integer field to a constant could not have failed, never, provided that target address is valid and not write-protected. That leaves two options:
- either your function sys_get_config() has crashed
- or it has returned an invalid pointer.

Since you say that the segfault is raised here, not in sys_get_config, the only thing left is the latter point: broken pointer.

Add to the sys_get_config some trivial printf that will dump the address-to-be-returned, then do the same in the calling function "func". Check whether it not-null, and also check if within sys_get_config it is the same as after being returned, just to be sure that calling conventions are proper, etc. A good idea for making a double/triple check is to also add inside the module "A" a copy of the function sys_get_config (with different name of course), and to check whether the addresses returned from sys_get_config and it's copy are the same. If they are not - something went very wrong during the linking

There is also a very very small chance that the module loading has been deferred, and you are trying to reference a memory of a module that was not fully initialized yet.. I worked on linux very long time ago, but I remember that dlopen has various loading options. But you wrote that you got the address by dlsym, so I suppose the module has loaded since you've got the symbol's final address..